# Image with Centered Text (part of the image) in 9 patch?

Tags: android, nine-patch

I am trying to create a 9patch png for a button in Android using an image with some static text and an icon in it. I used the 9 patch tool in the sdk but when I try to use the resulting png, I get malformed 9patch errors. Here is an image of what it looks like in the 9 patch editor...

[image: 9Patch editor]

Is this scenario possible or(is it because I have too many patches) or is my issue something else?

Comment: Use 9 patch image only for the background.Add text and icon using `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_drawable"`creating your button in xml.

Comment: @Android-Developer Yea that is what I was thinking I would have to do... What I really wanted to know is whether this scenario is possible using 9-patch or not since my designers gave me just images. So, do you know, is it possible in 9 patch or not?

Comment: Never tried to create an image like this,maybe it's possible,but I don't think it will look the same on all resolutions. So just stick up with the 9patch background and icons and text not part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what I discovered is that although possible, there are better solutions (the one mentioned above and described in more detail below)

I ended up going with the solution mentioned in the comment above. Creating a nine patch of the background/gradient and then floating the icon on the left and putting text as a property of the button itself. Works well enough!

As noted below by the commenter, this actually is possible as long as you don't have broken lines on the right or bottom of the 9patch... So If you took my above image and just removed the two lines on the bottom right side and the right bottom, it works like a charm (I'm still going to go with the other option however)

Comment: This is the "proper" way to do it indeed. The reason your original image was malformed was that the bottom/right black border lines of a 9patch are for the content area, not the stretch area. You can only have continuous lines for those, not broken in two as you had it.

Comment: @Geobits That makes sense, I didn't see that rule when I was looking through the documentation but now I understand :D

Comment: Now that you mention it, I'm not sure if it really *is* in the official documentation. The docs for this aren't very complete, IMHO. I've just never seen one work right with broken content area lines. I might have read it in some tutorial somewhere, I dunno.

Comment: @Geobits if you make your comment an answer I will accept it as it is more of an answer than mine :D

Comment: Nah, your answer looks good with the edits. Mine wasn't an answer in the first place because I wouldn't want to recommend to anyone to use text like that. Separated is a much cleaner way to do it.